# How to hide an item when today is not between 2 given dates?

Tags: php, date, select

I want to hide the items in a selectbox when the date is not between 2 given dates. 
For example: startdate is 5th of may and enddate is 16th of may. If today is the 10th then the item can be shown. If today is the 4th or the 24th, the item can't be shown.

I tried this:

```
<?php
echo "<select>";        
if(05-05-2013 < date("d-m-Y") AND 16-05-2013 < date("d-m-Y")){
echo "<style type='text/css'>
    .date{
        display: none;
    }
</style>";  
}


echo "<option class='date'>test1</option>";
echo "<option class='date'>test2</option>";

echo "</select>";
?>
```

and this:

```
<?php
echo "<option style='
if(05-05-2013 < date('d-m-Y') AND 16-05-2013 < date('d-m-Y'))
{ 
     echo 'display: none;'; 
}'>test</option>";
?>
```

But that doesn't work. Anybody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't even have those options in the `select` element if your condition for them showing is not met. In other words, don't hide them, remove them instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everybody.
I realised that I can filter this in my database. 

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CURDATE() >= `startdate` AND CURDATE()<=`enddate`

Answer (score 5):

```
$today = new DateTime();
$start = new DateTime('05-05-2013');
$end   = new DateTime('16-05-2013');

if ($today >= $start && $today <= $end)
{
    // show it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try out this

```
  $display_style = '';
if((strtotime('05-05-2013') < strtotime(date("d-m-Y"))) AND (strtotime('16-05-2013') < strtotime(date("d-m-Y")))){
$display_style =  "style='display:none;'";  
}

echo "<select ".$display_style.">";        
echo "<option class='date'>test1</option>";
echo "<option class='date'>test2</option>";

echo "</select>";
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Well for starters this will never compile because `05-05-2013` and `16-05-2013` isn't in quotes, and even if it was, you'd be comparing the strings.

Comment: i have updated my answer. sorry to add quik pls check @h2ooooooo

Comment: If I do it like this, the selectbox isn't vissible. I tried adding ".$display_style." to option, but then they are both vissible

Comment: have test it is in coming in if conditions if your current date is lower then both as you define at if statements ?

Answer (score 0):

Well the question is "I want to hide the items when the date is **not** between 2 given dates" so try this:

```
$date_compare='17-05-2013';
if($date_compare<'05-05-2013'||$date_compare>'16-05-2013'){//if date_compare not between 05-05-2013 and 16-05-2013 show
echo "<style type='text/css'>
        .date{
          display: none;
         }
       </style>";
}
```

Only shows the style when  the date is **not** between 2 given dates